# c++ c-string topper function sometimes outputs random numbers in the end

Tags: c++

I need to use a character array pointing to a function. In the function, I need it to make the input into all capital letters. I figured I'd use the toupper function, which worked great for certain input, but when I input certain words I end up getting weird symbols/numbers in the end of my output(see output). Any help?

#### Code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void allUppercase(char*);

const int SIZE = 50;

int main()
{
    char words[SIZE];

    cout << "Please enter your text : ";
    cin.get(words, (SIZE-1));

    cout << "The keyboard input was \"" << words << "\".\n";
    cout << "\nThe uppercase output is \"";
    allUppercase(words);
    cout << "\".\n";

    return 0;
}

// outputs the string entered in uppercase letters
// (Use a character array to store the string)
void allUppercase(char *ch)
{
    char temp[SIZE];

    for (int i=0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        if (ch[i] != '\0')
            temp[i] = toupper(ch[i]);
        else
            break;
    }
    cout << temp;
}
```

#### Example Output

[image: output]

Comment: `std::transform(words, words + SIZE, temp, toupper);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to null terminate `temp`.

```
void allUppercase(char *ch) {
    char temp[SIZE];

    for (int i=0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        if (ch[i] != '\0') {
            temp[i] = toupper(ch[i]);
        } else {
            temp[i] = '\0';
            break;
        }
    }
    cout << temp;
}
```

Comment: That did the trick. I figured that because it is a c-string, it would automatically have a NULL character somewhere in there, seeing as I left a space for one.

Comment: That code is needlessly complex. It would be a better answer without that code.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add a zero byte at the end of the result string.

For example,

```
void allUppercase( char const* s )
{
    char temp[SIZE];
    int i = 0;
    while( temp[i] = toupper( s[i] ) ) { ++i; }
    cout << temp;
}
```

Disclaimer: code not touched by compiler.

---

In other news, in order to work with national characters such as Norwegian æ, ø and å, with a single byte per character encoding that supports them, you need to

- cast the argument to `toupper` to `unsigned char`, and
- call `setlocale( LC_ALL, "" )` at the start of `main`.

Without the cast `toupper` can receive a negative argument value other than `EOF`, because `char` is usually a signed type, and in that case the behavior is undefined (e.g. a crash).

---

Also, instead of raw arrays and pointers, just use `std::string`. You have already included the `<string>` header.

Comment: I am fairly new to programming. This is actually a class assignment that I am working on and we are encouraged to use the "using namespace std" Sorry if it is not the professional way of coding.

Comment: @EdwardRios: I can't see that I've mentioned that, at all. But `using namespace std;` is there in the language for a reason. It's often convenient, the practical thing to do. In some cases it can be ungood, however, particularly in the global namespace in a header file. For example, that can force a name collision for `distance` on client code.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand what you were saying. It would be easier to use a string but I had to use a c-string according to my professor.

Answer (score 0):

the best way is to write a while loop like this

```
while(ch[i]!='\0')
{
temp[i] = toupper(ch[i]);
cout<<temp[i]
i++;
}
```

and this program will be terminated when '\0' is found

Comment: This gave me the line twice.